# Problem in using Customizer

Tags: functions, images, actions, theme-customizer

Looking for some help with a customizer problem. I am using following codes to create a customizer which will allow me to upload an image for topic of the week section. owever, the following codes doesn't seem to work properly and was not displaying image. Plzz help guys..

This is the function i am using in **functions.php**

```
/****************************************************/
/* Topic of the Week Thumb Uploader */
/***************************************************/

function cult_customizer_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'cult_topic_thumb' , array(
    'title'       => __( 'Topic of the Week' ),
    'priority'    => 36,
    'description' => 'Allows you to upload an image for your topic of the week section.',
) );
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'cult_custom_settings[display_topic_thumb]' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'cult_custom_settings[display_topic_thumb]', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Display Topic of the Week Thumb' ),
    'section'  => 'cult_topic_thumb',
    'settings' => 'cult_custom_settings[display_topic_thumb]',
) ) );
}
add_action('customize_register', 'cult_customizer_register');
```

This is my code in **index.php** for using customizer

```
<!-- topic of the week -->
        <div class="topic_week">
            <h1 class="section_heading"> TOPIC OF THE WEEK </h1>
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'cult_custom_settings[display_topic_thumb]' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="photo">
                <a href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>' rel='home'><img src='<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'cult_custom_settings[display_topic_thumb]' ) ); ?>' alt='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>'></a>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Only Change the code like this

```
function cult_customizer_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'cult_topic_thumb' , array(
    'title'       => __( 'Topic of the Week' ),
    'priority'    => 36,
    'description' => 'Allows you to upload an image for your topic of the week section.',
) );
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'display_topic_thumb' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'display_topic_thumb', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Display Topic of the Week Thumb' ),
    'section'  => 'cult_topic_thumb',
    'settings' => 'display_topic_thumb',
) ) );
}
add_action('customize_register', 'cult_customizer_register');
```

And in your index.php call diplay_topic_thumb

```
<div class="topic_week">
            <h1 class="section_heading"> TOPIC OF THE WEEK </h1>
            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'display_topic_thumb' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="photo">
                <a href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>' rel='home'><img src='<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'display_topic_thumb' ) ); ?>' alt='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>'></a>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

It will work fine for you